# Dynamically adding a button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I've got an mvc app in .net that i'm trying to dynamically add buttons. Below is a sample of the jquery i'm using. It's a fairly long sequence of html that's appended but it works and those buttons are added. But when the buttons click they don't seem to activate a click event handler that i've got.

```
$('#imageCont').append('<div class="row tier" id="tier'+ tierIdCount +'"  ><hr/><h3>Tier</h3><button type="button" class="btn btn-default addPerson">Add Person</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default removePerson">Remove Person</button></div>');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you have event handler with jQuery like this:

```
$('.removePerson').on('click', 
   function(e){
       //do some stuff
   });
```

And if you changed this first line with

```
$(document).on('click', '.removePerson',
   function(e){
       //do some stuff
   });
```

everything should start working as you expect. Dynamically added html elements have to use delegated events, because listeners are attached to elements which are already present in DOM